Kong : {"message":"no Route matched with those values"}
I had tried https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/ and I am able to register service and router both but when I am calling the kong to redirect its giving below error.
service registered:
{
  "next": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "host": "testapp",
      "id": "722f19aa-101d-586e-8ecc-13994d576b46",
      "created_at": 1725516638,
      "path": null,
      "enabled": true,
      "write_timeout": 60000,
      "client_certificate": null,
      "tags": null,
      "ca_certificates": null,
      "port": 3003,
      "updated_at": 1725516638,
      "read_timeout": 60000,
      "name": "test_service_kong",
      "protocol": "http",
      "tls_verify": null,
      "connect_timeout": 60000,
      "tls_verify_depth": null,
      "retries": 5
    }
  ]
}

router registered :
{
  "next": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "path_handling": "v0",
      "paths": [
        "/api/v1"
      ],
      "id": "b8dc7e31-996f-50c8-9f40-0905e6703c27",
      "sources": null,
      "created_at": 1725516638,
      "request_buffering": true,
      "strip_path": true,
      "destinations": null,
      "https_redirect_status_code": 426,
      "methods": [
        "GET"
      ],
      "snis": null,
      "tags": null,
      "service": {
        "id": "722f19aa-101d-586e-8ecc-13994d576b46"
      },
      "updated_at": 1725516638,
      "hosts": null,
      "name": "test_route_kong",
      "regex_priority": 0,
      "preserve_host": false,
      "response_buffering": true,
      "protocols": [
        "http",
        "https"
      ],
      "headers": null
    }
  ]
}

calling for kong on: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/
so that it can redirect to http://localhost:3003/
{"message":"no Route matched with those values"}

Regarding to strip_path I read the documentation, but it is not clear for me:
So, how strip_path attribute value is applied here?

Please report the exact steps you made to create the service and the route, or provide a MRE. Are Kong and the service running on Docker, are them standalone applications or something else? Is the service accessible from localhost:3003?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
